# Collection View with self sizing cells not scrollable horizontally anymore

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I set up a collection view and got all working with fixed `height` and `width` for the cells.

Now I would like to have my Cells self sized, so I found that I can add

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)
    menuCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

With above code my cell resizes by the width (as wanted), but my collection view is not scrollable horizontally anymore, but instead lays out the cells vertically.

Is `estimatedItemSize` only thought to work for vertical scrolling? What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scroll direction of a UICollectionViewFlowLayout is vertical, so you need to set the scrollDirection for the new layout, too:

```
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
```

Comment: Thank YOU (Ron Swanson xD)! I am working with Storyboard, I wouldn't have thought of this. :D

Comment: Yes, if you do not plan to replace the FlowLayout the Storyboard sets for you, everthings fine. But you are creating a new one, overwriting the one from the Storyboard. Glad I could help :)